# Return XPath for each line in XML file in Groovy

Tags: xml, csv, xpath, groovy, soapui

I want to parse an XML file and create a new CSV where each XML tag is next to it's own XPath.

This is in SoapUI. I've tried using the XMLSlurper, but I can't quite grasp the logic of it, and my attempts to see what's happening in the log are not working.

```
def String showTheXPath() {
    def input = "input.txt"

    def root = new XmlSlurper().parseText(input) 

    def  xpath1 = root.Vehicle.Car.Prius.text();
    def  xpath2 = root.Vehicle.Boat.text();

    log.info xpath1
}
```

Ideally this code would return a CSV file that looks like this with the XML tags in the first column, and each tag's XPath in the second column:

```
<Vehicle>                   |  Vehicle
  <Car>                     |  Vehicle/Car
    <Prius>2018</Prius>     |  Vehicle/Car/Prius
    <Bentley>2015</Bentley> |  Vehicle/Car/Bentley
  </Car>                    |  Vehicle/Car
  <Boat>                    |  Vehicle/Boat
    <Yacht>2011</Yacht>     |  Vehicle/Boat/Yacht
  </Boat>                   |  Vehicle/Boat
  <Bicycle/>                |  Vehicle/Bicycle
</Vehicle>                  |  Vehicle
```

Comment: I might be able to cook something... Could you please clarify what you want to achieve. Is it important to get the xpaths in the exact order each node appears in the XML, or would you be happy with getting the xpath in any order, but simply knowing they are all there...? And how about any attributes inside the tags? Do you have namespaces in your XML, or is it okay to ignore them if they are present?

Comment: Hello @Steen, thanks for the question! I need the XPath to have the correct order for finding the tags in future projects, and the XML does have namespaces which should be excluded!

Comment: Help pls, given my answer and its comments from @Steen, can you please provide a more thorough example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: @DmitryKhamitov I can! The goal is for the CSV to have one column returning the XML file with its proper indentations, and the second column returning the XPath without worrying about repeated tags. I'll update the example

Comment: @Helppls you can recheck my answer. As you clarified, without indexing repeating tags. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Here it is. Depth-first traversal:

```
class XmlToPath {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        def input = """
<Vehicle>
  <Car>
    <Prius/>
  </Car>
  <Boat>
    <Yacht/>
  </Boat>
  <Bicycle/> 
</Vehicle>
"""
        def root = new XmlParser().parseText(input)
        traverse(root)
    }

    static void traverse(Node node) {
        def path = path(node)
        println(path)
        def children = node.children()
        if (children) {
            children.each {
                traverse(it)
            }
            println(path)
        }
    }

    static String path(Node node) {
        def parent = node.parent()
        if (parent) {
            "${path(parent)}/${node.name()}"
        } else {
            node.name()
        }
    }
}
```

Output as expected:

```
Vehicle
Vehicle/Car
Vehicle/Car/Prius
Vehicle/Car
Vehicle/Boat
Vehicle/Boat/Yacht
Vehicle/Boat
Vehicle/Bicycle
Vehicle
```

And here is `traverse` and `path` version which prints a complete CSV with formatted XML in the first column as you want to achieve:

```
static void traverse(Node node) {
    def tags = path(node)
    def path = tags.join("/")
    def indent = ' ' * ((tags.size() - 1) * 2)
    def nodeName = node.name()
    def children = node.children()
    if (children) {
        println("$indent<$nodeName>|$path")
        children.each {
            traverse(it)
        }
        println("$indent</$nodeName>|$path")
    } else {
        println("$indent<$nodeName/>|$path")
    }
}

static List<String> path(Node node) {
    def parent = node.parent()
    if (parent) {
        path(parent).tap {
            add(node.name())
        }
    } else {
        [node.name()]
    }
}
```

Output with formatted XML but without pipes alignment:

```
<Vehicle>|Vehicle
  <Car>|Vehicle/Car
    <Prius/>|Vehicle/Car/Prius
  </Car>|Vehicle/Car
  <Boat>|Vehicle/Boat
    <Yacht/>|Vehicle/Boat/Yacht
  </Boat>|Vehicle/Boat
  <Bicycle/>|Vehicle/Bicycle
</Vehicle>|Vehicle
```

And finally, here is a pretty-formatted version of CSV. I hope you've got the idea and can adjust the solution to your needs/preferences:

```
class XmlToPath {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        def input = """
<Vehicle>
  <Car>
    <Prius/>
  </Car>
  <Boat>
    <Yacht/>
  </Boat>
  <Bicycle/> 
</Vehicle>
"""
        def root = new XmlParser().parseText(input)
        def printer = []
        traverse(root, printer)
        def width = printer.max { tagAndPath ->
            tagAndPath[0].size()
        }[0].size()
        printer.each { tag, path ->
            printf("%-${width}s  |  %s%n", tag, path)
        }
    }

    static void traverse(Node node, List printer) {
        def tags = path(node)
        def path = tags.join("/")
        def indent = ' ' * ((tags.size() - 1) * 2)
        def nodeName = node.name()
        def children = node.children()
        if (children) {
            printer << ["$indent<$nodeName>", path]
            children.each {
                traverse(it, printer)
            }
            printer << ["$indent</$nodeName>", path]
        } else {
            printer << ["$indent<$nodeName/>", path]
        }
    }

    static List<String> path(Node node) {
        def parent = node.parent()
        if (parent) {
            path(parent).with {
                add(node.name())
                it
            }
        } else {
            [node.name()]
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<Vehicle>     |  Vehicle
  <Car>       |  Vehicle/Car
    <Prius/>  |  Vehicle/Car/Prius
  </Car>      |  Vehicle/Car
  <Boat>      |  Vehicle/Boat
    <Yacht/>  |  Vehicle/Boat/Yacht
  </Boat>     |  Vehicle/Boat
  <Bicycle/>  |  Vehicle/Bicycle
</Vehicle>    |  Vehicle
```

Comment: I like the approach. However, it may turn out not solving the issue. Example: If the <Car> node is actually just one of a list of <Car> nodes, you will then have to return the exact node number in your xpath like "Vahicle/Car[3]/Prius. You don't.

Comment: @Steen thanks for the feedback. I'd suggest the OP to give a more thorough example then

Comment: @DmitryKhamitov I apologize for how long it's taking me to come to a decision, I can't figure out how to have this code run in SoapUI. The pretty-formatted version gave me the error: `org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.tap() is applicable for argument types: (XmlToPath$_path_closure4)`

Comment: @Helppls my bad :) `tap` was introduced in Groovy 2.5.0. I've updated the answer by replacing the `tap` method with `with`. It should work now

Answer (score 0):

I think this may do what you intend to do. This is somewhat inspired by Dmitry Khamitovs suggested solution. I've certainly copy/pasted some of it.

Be advised, that it makes no sense to make xpaths for the end tags. So I've omitted those from the suggested solution.

You should be able to copy/paste this into a Groovy Step in SoapUI and run it as-is.

I've also modified the example XML to include more than one  element inside  to illustrate the handling of a list of elements.

The xpath built will always return an index, which by default will be [1]. This is because every single node is potentially the first element in a list. There is no way of knowing if this is the case, without either peeping ahead in the XML or looking into the schema. This will complicate the solution, and you will only get a somewhat slimmer xpath that in the end will return the same result.

To get your CSV file, you may want to adjust the printStack. Currently it just outputs to the log.

```
def input = """
<Vehicles>
 <ns1:Cars xmlns:ns1="asdf"  xmlns:ns2="ieurieur">
  <ns2:Car>
    <Prius/>
  </ns2:Car>
  <ns2:Car>
    <Ka/>
  </ns2:Car>
  </ns1:Cars>
  <Boat>
    <Yacht/>
  </Boat>
  <Bicycle/> 
</Vehicles>
"""
def root = new XmlParser().parseText(input)
java.util.Stack nodeStack = new java.util.Stack<String>()
traverse(root,1,nodeStack)
return

void traverse(Node node, Integer index, java.util.Stack stack) {
    def nsposition = new Integer(node.name().toString().indexOf("}"))
    nsposition++
    def nodename = node.name().toString().substring(nsposition)
    stack.push(nodename + "[" + index + "]")
    def path = buildPath(stack)
    printStack(nodename,stack)
    def children = node.children()
    def childCount = new java.util.HashMap<String,Integer>()
    if (children) {
        children.each {
            def count = getIndex(it.name(),childCount)
            childCount.put(it.name(),count)
            traverse(it,count,stack)
        }
    }
    stack.pop()
}

void printStack(def nodename, def stack) {
    def indentation = ""
    for (def x=0; x<stack.size(); x++) {
        indentation += "    "
    }
    def path = ""
    for (def element : stack.elements()) {
        path += "/${element}"
    }
    log.info "${indentation}<${nodename}>|${path}"
}

Integer getIndex(def name, def childCount) {
    if (childCount.containsKey(name)) {
        return childCount.get(name) + 1
    }
    else {
        return 1
    }
}

String buildPath(def stack) {
    def result = ""
    for (def element : stack.elements()) {
        result += "/" + element
    }
    return result
}
```

Sample output from the log:

```
Tue May 21 15:59:13 CEST 2019: INFO:    <Vehicles>|/Vehicles[1]
Tue May 21 15:59:13 CEST 2019: INFO:        <Cars>|/Vehicles[1]/Cars[1]
Tue May 21 15:59:13 CEST 2019: INFO:            <Car>|/Vehicles[1]/Cars[1]/Car[1]
Tue May 21 15:59:13 CEST 2019: INFO:                <Prius>|/Vehicles[1]/Cars[1]/Car[1]/Prius[1]
Tue May 21 15:59:13 CEST 2019: INFO:            <Car>|/Vehicles[1]/Cars[1]/Car[2]
Tue May 21 15:59:13 CEST 2019: INFO:                <Ka>|/Vehicles[1]/Cars[1]/Car[2]/Ka[1]
Tue May 21 15:59:13 CEST 2019: INFO:        <Boat>|/Vehicles[1]/Boat[1]
Tue May 21 15:59:13 CEST 2019: INFO:            <Yacht>|/Vehicles[1]/Boat[1]/Yacht[1]
Tue May 21 15:59:13 CEST 2019: INFO:        <Bicycle>|/Vehicles[1]/Bicycle[1]
```

Comment: I made a few adjustments, and I think it now handles namespaces acceptably. The adjustment is quick-and-dirty and BUG UGLY, but it gets the job done. I will probably be able to do something better, but alas, right now I don't have the time.